# Can't save result set into variable in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the problem with saving result set data into variable in MySQL.
I expect that `Select @var` shows me the all result set but it show me only  the last one row. Here is screenshot:
[image]

Is that my mistake or incomprehension of variable concepts in MySql?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value of variable `@id` is changing for every record. So it is currently having the last changed value.

For saving all id's from product table you can use `GROUP_CONCAT` like this:

```
SELECT @id := GROUP_CONCAT(id) 
FROM products;
SELECT @id;
```

Answer (score 1):

id_var is variable the last time it was updated it had value "`9`" , so it is showing you `"9`". it is updated with each row

for example if you `orderby` id DESC it will show you `1`